# What if NATS message payload contains \n\r?

Tags: nats.io, nats-streaming-server

I am trying to write a client library for NATS.io. According to the protocol [here](https://nats.io/documentation/internals/nats-protocol/), `\n\r` is used to delimiting commands, payload, etc.

`INFO {"server_id":"1ec445b504f4edfb4cf7927c707dd717","version":"0.6.6","go":"go1.4.2","host":"0.0.0.0","port":4222,"auth_required":false,"ssl_required":false,"max_payload":1048576}`

My question is what if the payload contains `\r\n`? I couldn't find any information about how to escape `\r\n`. Should one read `INFO` until a valid JSON is received and not look for `\r\n` as delimiter?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

A subscribe message `MSG` always contains the length of the payload bytes.
[docu](https://nats.io/documentation/internals/nats-server-protocol/#MSG)

#### Example

`MSG FOO.BAR 9 11\r\nHello World\r\n`

The payload are the 11 bytes after the first`\r\n` ---> `Hello World`

#### Example with \r\n in the payload

`MSG FOO.BAR 9 11\r\nHello W\r\nld\r\n`

The payload are the 11 bytes after the first`\r\n` ---> `Hello W\r\nld`